# Forwarding local network interface on my server through NAT

Tags: routing, ip, linux-networking

I have 3 interfaces on my server,

- first is used for the local network,
- second and third are internet connections (each has its own ip routing table).

How can i force server daemons and command line tools use first interface to create outgoing connections. I want use same iptables nat and filter rules for my server that i use for other machines of my network.

```
eth0 192.168.0.1
eth1 9.9.9.9
eth2 9.9.9.10
```

I don't know why it uses eth1 for outgoing connections now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run

```
ip route
```

It will give you results similar to the following:

```
default via 192.168.0.10 dev eth0  metric 2
127.0.0.0/8 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.106  metric 2
```

As you can see from the above output, any traffic which goes via the default route will go via eth0

So it sounds like you need to do something like this:

```
ip route delete default via <ip> dev eth1
```

then

```
ip route add default via <ip> dev eth0
```

How you make this change permanent will depend on your distro.